# nested for loops inside templates

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
     level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     todo = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     content = models.TextField()
     timestamp = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
     datestamp = models.DateField( auto_now=True)
     like = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='user_likes', blank=True)
     is_verified=models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.title

     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student:task-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

     objects = PostManager()

     @property
     def comments(self):
        instance = self
        qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
        return qs

     @property
     def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type


class Images(models.Model):
     post = models.ForeignKey(Task, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image',blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

I have two models Task and Images. Im storing multiple images for a task saved . I want to display the list of tasks using pagination and also images inside each task.

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
@page_template('student_dash_page.html')
def StudentDashView(request,template='student_dash.html',  extra_context=None):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('accounts:index')
    task = Task.objects.all().order_by('timestamp')
    images = Images.objects.filter(post=task)
    notifications =  Notification.objects.filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(task, 10)
    try:
        tasks = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        tasks = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        tasks= paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'notifications': notifications,
        'nbar': 'home',
        'task': tasks,
        'images': images
    }
    if not request.user.is_client:
        return HttpResponse("You are in trainer account")
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return render(request, template, context)
```

How do i get the images to display correctly inside the template using for loops

Im trying

```
  {% for obj in task %}
  <p>{{ obj.title }}

  {% for image in images %}
   <img src="{{ image.url }}"</img>
   {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
```

Im getting the error: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. And you don't seem to be using formsets at all - where are they?

Comment: Im using formsets as to save the models when submitting the form.This is for displaying.The images are saving correctly! @DanielRoseman

Comment: But you mentioned formsets twice, and I don't understand how they are relevant to your question. You still need to show the traceback.

Comment: sorry for confusing.Edited! @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't make any sense:

```
images = Images.objects.filter(post=task)
```

because `task` is a queryset of all the Task instances.

You don't need to get the images at all in the view. Remove that line and the other references, and just do this in the template:

```
{% for obj in task %}
    <p>{{ obj.title }}</p>

    {% for image in obj.images_set.all %}
      <img src="{{ image.image.url }}"</img> 
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Note also, the Image object has a field called `image`, and that's what you need to access the url attribute on.

(For the sake of database efficiency, you might want to change your query slightly in the view:

```
task = Task.objects.all().order_by('timestamp').prefetch_related('images_set')
```

otherwise every iteration will cause a separate db call to get the related images. You don't need to do this to make things work, though.)

Comment: Cannot find 'images' on Task object, 'images' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the correct models? That would work given what you have shown above. Could the model actually be called `Image` rather than `Images`? Does it work without the prefetch_related?

Comment: It is also not pulling any images

Comment: It is not working without prefetch_related . The models are correct

Comment: fixed the issue . It should be {% for image in obj.images_set.all %}

Comment: Apologies. And the prefetch_related should have been `images_set`. Both corrected.

Comment: Great! Huge respect!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future readers that it helped solve the problem.