# Two layer for loops to demonstrate list in django template

Tags: django

I want to demonstrate two layer "for" loops in one template html page in django. The first layer is topics and the second is entries under each topics. Here's the view.py for topics and topic.

```
def topics(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by("date_added")
    context = {"topics": topics}
    return render(request, "project/topics.html", context)
def topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entries.order_by("-date_added")
    context = {"entries": entries}
    return render(request, "project/topic.html", context)
```

In the topics.html template, I want to demonstrate topics and every entries under each topic as following. But how could I achieve that?

```
{% for topic in topics %}
  <a href="{% url 'project:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic.text }}</a>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <a href="{% url 'project:entry' entry.id %}">{{ entry.text }}</a>
```

I try the link provided ([nested for loops inside templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984538/nested-for-loops-inside-templates)), but it seems not working. Here's the script in template. Can you kindly help?

```
{% for topic in topics %} 
  {% for entry in topic.entries_set.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'project:entry' entry.id %}">{{ entry.text }}</a>
  {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Here's the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def _str_(self):
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="entries")
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def _str_(self):
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
        #on_delete=models.CASCADE,
```

Comment: Show your models. Do Entries have a foreign key to Topics?

Comment: yes. it has the foreign key.

Comment: Sorry, I follow the instruction from the link but still no results showing.

Comment: You should probably show your models. It looks like you have defined the `related_name` as `entries`, so you should use that: `topic.entries.all()`.

Comment: Just add the model here.

Comment: Yes, so did using `{% for entry in topic.entries.all %}` work?

Comment: There's error: Reverse for 'entry' not found. 'entry' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Well that is a completely different problem. Do you have such a URL? You should probably ask a new question including your template and urls.py.

Comment: Yes, I think that is maybe the problem. Will check and update it later.

Comment: Just check the problem and edit the url for it. Thx!